# Error parsing CSV with FasterCSV gem (MalformedCSVError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, fastercsv

FasterCSV is raising MalformedCSVError (Illegal Quoting) in this line:

```
|0150|1161623|Medicamentos e genericos "EPP".|1423|PB|
```

This is the code:

```
FasterCSV.foreach(path_to_file, :col_sep => '|') do |row|
    ...
end
```

Any ideas?
tks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also an option `quote_char` which defaults to `"`, try changing it to something, which you don't expect in your data. You might try `nil` but I have never tried that.

```
FasterCSV.foreach(path_to_file, :col_sep => '|', :quote_char => "|") do |row|
  ...
end
```